# Redirect everything but 1 URL and it's sub URL's

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-alias

I'm trying to redirect everything on a website but 1 Joomla URL (and URLS containing this keyword). Example:

Should redirect everything from www.mydomain.com to www.mynewdomain.com but this:

> www.mydomain.com/home/index.php/quality/*

I tried something like this:

```
RedirectMatch 302 /home/index.php/(?!quality)  http://www.mynewdomain.com
```

But It won't redirect / or /home. Also, I tried the following but won't work:

```
RedirectMatch 302 (?!quality)  http://www.mynewdomain.com
```

Is there a way to archive this?

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/((?!home/index\.php/quality/.*).+)$  http://www.mynewdomain.com/$1
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. This would be a correct solution, but I totally forgot that in order to properly load data from /quality, It's necessary to keep access the basic Joomla directories (images/templates/admin panel). I fixed it just adding exceptions to the redirection.